# why the ChannelHandler passed to io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2MultiplexCodecBuilder#forServer needed to be @Sharable?

Tags: netty

Why not bind the ChannelHandler to specific EventLoop so that I don't need to care about thread safe problem thus improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is re-used for different streams which may use different `EventLoop`s. If your handler is not you can just use a `ChannelInitializer` that will add your `ChannelHandler`.